# WMI query issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query

***Here is where I have started:***

```
#Get Physical Memory
function getwmiinfo ($svr) {


gwmi -query "select * from
     Win32_PhysicalMemory" -computername $svr | select [$svr], DeviceLocator 

}


$Servers = get-content -path "C:\test.txt"


foreach($Servers in $Servers) {


 getwmiinfo $Servers

}
```

***I get this:***

```
[risk]                 DeviceLocator
------                 -------------
                       DIMM0
                       DIMM1
```

What I want is this:

```
ServerName             DeviceLocator
----------             -------------
RISK                   DIMM0
RISK                   DIMM1
```

Is this possible?  How would I do it.  I have spent hours on this and can't quite get it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace `[$svr]` with `ServerName`, because `[$svr]` isn't a field you can select.

Also, I'd change

```ps1
foreach($Servers in $Servers) {


 getwmiinfo $Servers

}
```

to

```ps1
foreach($Server in $Servers) {
 getwmiinfo $Server
}
```

**Notice the variable name change in the foreach statement**

**Update**

```
gwmi -query "select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory" | select __SERVER, DeviceLocator
```

Comment: Making the changes you suggested provides me with this: 
      ServerName DeviceLocator 
      ---------- ------------- 
                 DIMM0 DIMM1

Comment: Updated with modified select.